# meta_query returning excluded result

Tags: wp-query, array, meta-query

I have a series of day slots per location, in a multicheckbox custom field. I have a search page where the user can select location, weekday desired, and activity type. Right now I just have 2 samples: a class that meets on Tuesdays and one that does not. When searching for a Tuesday class, however, both are showing up. Here is how I build my argument:

```
$searchday = $day; // save this value for the results_array
                        $day = array();
                        for($a=1; $a<=10; $a++) {
                            $day[$a] = array(
                                'key' => '_cmb_'.$searchday.'_location_'.$a,
                                'value' => $location,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                );
                        }

$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_type' => $class_type,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                                (($day) ? $day : ''),

                                             ),
                        );
```

And here is that output as `print_r`

```
Array
(
[posts_per_page] => -1
[post_type] => aquatics
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => OR
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_1
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_2
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_3
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_4
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_5
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_6
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_7
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_8
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_9
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_10
                        [value] => huntley
                        [compare] => LIKE
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I went so far as to examine the database to ensure that this class (which should not show up) holds no value for meta_key '_cmb_tuesday_location_1' .. 2, 3, etc - through 10. No key should mean `huntley` value is not found. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure about this one, but i think you have too many nested arrays.

you should be getting something like

```
[meta_query] => Array
(
    [relation] => OR
    [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_1
                    [value] => huntley
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )

    [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _cmb_tuesday_location_2
                    [value] => huntley
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )
```

you can add the conditions directly to the right array:

```
                    [...]
                    $metaq = array();
                    $metaq[relation] = 'OR'
                    for($a=1; $a<=10; $a++) {
                        $metaq[$a] = array(
                            'key' => '_cmb_'.$searchday.'_location_'.$a,
                            'value' => $location,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            );
                    }
```

and then

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,
          'post_type' => $class_type,
          'meta_query' => $metaq
);
```

note: i haven't tested this, sorry

Comment: You're right I think. But how do I get that? I really need to check against all of these fields, so I made `$day` ben array which itself carries lots of arrays. Is there a cleaner way to include that array of arrays in the argument's `meta_query` without having to write out `$day[1].$day[2]...` etc? Can't really do a `foreach` inside this variable definition.

Comment: you can use your array directly to the meta_query . i've updated the response for this

Comment: This generates a very good looking `$args` but the page is now stuck in an infinite loop of loading. Never gets to the result. If I leave off the `$day['relation'] = 'OR';` part, it displays no results (because AND is default). So this seems to be what is breaking it, despite it appearing to look correct in my `print_r`

Comment: It works if I choose 'AND' (shows no results). I think my query might be too expensive because it is checking all of these values. Might have to research another method. Thank you for your help.

Comment: hm, i wonder.. do you mind posting the output of `$tuesdays = new WP_Query($args);
echo "tuesday query: {$tuesdays->request}";`

Comment: Here's the thing - it dies on creating the `new WP_Query()` when I use an `OR` joiner. Check out this ticket on core, which seems closely related: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18105 . I cannot echo anything after the query is created, because that's where it blows up the CPU apparently. Edit: I can actually get it to return a result if I reduce `$a` above to something small like `2`. I think I will create a new checkbox that generally indicates whether there are any classes available in given location, and just search for those here.